# Upgrade Magento 1.7.2 to 1.8.1 via Magento Connect

Tags: upgrade, magento-connect

I was reading the upgrade guide - but had the idea to try the upgrade via Magento connect. THis has always worked before ;P

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-upgrade-roadmap

Is there a real reason why we should not upgrade via Magento Connect in backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up upgrading our whole store using Magento connect

We did encounter missing some JS files, but after fixing that we were fine

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/664565/

[Magento 1.8.1 quick create no longer working JS error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16007/magento-1-8-1-quick-create-no-longer-working-js-error)

It is still th easiest way

Comment: I did it this way and worked fine but avoid the temptation to just switch the js folder old for new like I did - the js folder is used for extensions. In the end I just added the scripaculuous folder to it from the official 1.8 version.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no any third party or local extensions that store theirs templates and layout files in `app\design\frontend\base\default` everything should be ok.

I am not sure but during updating `Mage_Core_Modules` magento should delete everything what is inside `app\design\frontend\base\default` and copy new version files there.

So double check that.

Comment: Delete all like in *.*? Or does it delete the new files it will later save in app\design\frontend\base\default