# Magento 1.8.1 quick create no longer working JS error

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, javascript, products-management, ce-1.8.1.0

Hi we installed Magento 1.8.1 and now quick create is no longer for configurable products

I think it is an JS error (See below), but no idea why

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):152
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sortable is not defined 5195b90b81e42880d3e54d723d6ed9e3-1393101403.js:1382
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'quickCreateNewProduct' of undefined (index):2433
onclick
```

**Question: Did anyone encounter this one too? or know how to fix?**

Do I need to maybe update my JS scripts manually

This is where it happens

```
<span id="create_button"><button  id="id_8f01c149ffc97ffcb5de0bc30f30d712" title="Quick Create" type="button" class="scalable save" onclick="superProduct.quickCreateNewProduct()" style=""><span><span><span>Quick Create</span></span></span></button></span>            </td>
    <td class="scope-label"><span class="nobr"></span></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aha! This solved our problem

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/664565/

We upgraded to Magento 1.8.1 (from 1.7.1) using Magento Connect. Apparently not all JS scripts were upgraded and some missing.

To solve: We downloaded stock Magento 1.8.1 and uploaded the complete JS directory overwriting all files.

Now it all works fine ;P Thanks for all the help

(and unexpected)

Answer (score 0):

From the name of javascript file I can suggest that you use merge js files (`System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Settings`).

Try to regenerate merged files. Go to `System -> Cache Management` and press button `Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache`.

If that doesn't help disable merging and you will see the exact javascript file where error occures.